# Continuous QR-Code scanning in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, qr-code

Question asked just to give solution :)

Main idea is to recognize QR-code on Unity without ANY additional action like tapping on the screen or sth like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(For me it's not necessary that "vuforia free" have watermark, so here is my solution)*

*(Also Vuforia works with camera much faster and no need to realize manually autofocus)*

Continious QR code recognition using Vuforia as webcam source and ZXing Library as QR recognizer

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using ZXing;

public class QRCodeReader : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool _isFrameFormatSet;

    IBarcodeReader _barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating("Autofocus", 2f, 2f);
    }

    void Autofocus () {
        CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_TRIGGERAUTO);

        RegognizeQR();
    }

    private Vuforia.Image GetCurrFrame()
    {
        return CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraImage(Vuforia.Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.GRAYSCALE);
    }

    void RegognizeQR()
    {
        if (!_isFrameFormatSet == _isFrameFormatSet)
        {
            _isFrameFormatSet = CameraDevice.Instance.SetFrameFormat(Vuforia.Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.GRAYSCALE, true);
        }

        var currFrame = GetCurrFrame();

        if (currFrame == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Camera image capture failure;");
        }
        else
        {
            var imgSource = new RGBLuminanceSource(currFrame.Pixels, currFrame.BufferWidth, currFrame.BufferHeight, true);

            var result = _barcodeReader.Decode(imgSource);
            if (result != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("RECOGNIZED: " + result.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its possible to realize also without Vuforia, ofc. Unity provides the possibility to get a camera and show it’s input on a webcamtexture. It's possible to find more documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html).

ZXing lib you can find [here](https://medium.com/@adrian.n/reading-and-generating-qr-codes-with-c-in-unity-3d-the-easy-way-a25e1d85ba51), or build it by your own hands using [sourse code located on github](https://github.com/zxing/zxing).

Both libs is cross-platform, so must be no issues on different devices.